# jquery pop up window trouble

Tags: css, jquery

i am using this jquery function to display a pop window. in this code it works fine for paragraph or div attribute with a css id. but i want to use it a several times in my html file, so i need to convert the id's to classes.
here is my js file:

```
//0 means disabled; 1 means enabled;
var popupStatus = 0;

//loading popup with jQuery magic!
function loadPopup(){
    //loads popup only if it is disabled
    if(popupStatus==0){
        $("#backgroundPopup").css({
            "opacity": "0.7"
        });
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#popupContact").fadeIn("slow");
        popupStatus = 1;
    }
}

//disabling popup with jQuery magic!
function disablePopup(){
    //disables popup only if it is enabled
    if(popupStatus==1){
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#popupContact").fadeOut("slow");
        popupStatus = 0;
    }
}

//centering popup
function centerPopup(){
    //request data for centering
    var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var popupHeight = $("#popupContact").height();
    var popupWidth = $("#popupContact").width();
    //centering
    $("#popupContact").css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": windowHeight/2-popupHeight/3.25,
        "left": windowWidth/2-popupWidth/2
    });
    //only need force for IE6

    $("#backgroundPopup").css({
        "height": windowHeight
    });

}


//CONTROLLING EVENTS IN jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){

    //LOADING POPUP
    //Click the button event!
    $("#button").click(function(){
        //centering with css
        centerPopup();
        //load popup
        loadPopup();
    });

    //CLOSING POPUP
    //Click the x event!
    $("#popupContactClose").click(function(){
        disablePopup();
    });
    //Click out event!
    $("#backgroundPopup").click(function(){
        disablePopup();
    });
    //Press Escape event!
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode==27 && popupStatus==1){
            disablePopup();
        }
    });

});
```

here is the css:

```
#backgroundPopup{
display:none;
position:fixed;
_position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6*/
height:100%;
width:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
background:#000000;
border:1px solid #cecece;
z-index:1;
}
#popupContact{
display:none;
position:fixed;
_position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6*/
width:470px;
background:#FFFFFF;
border:2px solid #cecece;
z-index:2;
padding:12px;
font-size:13px;
}
#popupContact h1{
text-align:left;
color:#6FA5FD;
font-size:22px;
font-weight:700;
border-bottom:1px dotted #D3D3D3;
padding-bottom:2px;
margin-bottom:20px;
}
#popupContactClose{
font-size:14px;
line-height:14px;
right:6px;
top:4px;
position:absolute;
color:#6fa5fd;
font-weight:700;
display:block;
cursor: pointer;
}
#button{
text-align:left;
}
```

and here is html:

```
<div id="button"><input type="submit" value="submit" /></div>
<div id="popupContact">
        <a id="popupContactClose">x</a>
        <h1>Description</h1>
        <p id="contactArea">
            <?php echo $data['description'];?>
        </p>
</div>
<div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
```

it works perfectly, when it is set for div with a css id.but now, if i change all those '#'s to '.'s to make the id's into classes, it doesn't work. how do make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you must clear your browsercache. If you change all `#` to `.` and all `id` to `class` it must work....[for more informations click here](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Changed to class from id's it's working fine for me